# URL Parsing with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript

I need to have a URL Parser written in JavaScript, that will work as described below:

Assuming you have this URL `http://www.somedomain.com/a/b/c`

Then the function `parseURL(n)` will work as follows:

```
var paramA = parseURL(1) // Sets paramA to "a"
var paramB = parseURL(2) // Sets paramB to "b"
var paramC = parseURL(3) // Sets paramC to "c"
var paramD = parseURL(4) // Sets paramD to null (because the path does not ripple down to d)
```

also note that if I pass this URL `http://www.somedomain.com/a/b/c/` (note that I added a backslash at the end of the URL) then the function will still work the same way.

This function should work on any URL of any length, so it should work on a longer URL as this one: `http://www.somedomain.com/a/b/c/d/e/`. For this URL. we can go up to `parseURL(5)` which should return "e", but `parseURL(6)` or `parseURL(7)` will both return null.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the backslash that you supposedly added. Is the note wrong, or the URL?

Comment: The original URL is `http://www.somedomain.com/a/b/c` and the other URL is `http://www.somedomain.com/a/b/c/` (note that the second URL has a backslash).

Comment: http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/backslash.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function parseURL(i) {
   var t = document.location.pathname.split('/');
   return i < t.length ? t[i] : null;
}
```

As pointed by VisioN, to deal with ending `/`, this version would be better :

```
function parseURL(i) {
   var t = document.location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/, "").split('/');
   return i < t.length ? t[i] : null;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to add `replace`: `document.location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/, "").split('/');`.

Comment: @VisionN In fact it depends on the goal. But I'd suggest you to make another answer if you feel it's needed. I *know* you would have found what I wrote yourself so it won't be copy-paste...

Comment: According to the basic idea, the OP wants `/a/b/c` to be parsed in the same way as `/a/b/c/`. Hence `parseURL(4)` must return `null`, whereas in your case it will return `""`.

Comment: @VisioN Edited. Now it's free for everyone to edit it...

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I fixed the return value in the original code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will take a url string and return an array. It is indexed the way you described with the addition that the host name is index 0. Not sure if you wanted that or what dystroy wrote which will parse your current URL.

So for `parseURL("http://www.somedomain.com/a/b/c/")`
you will get an array that is

```
urlParts[0] = "www.somedomain.com"
urlParts[1] = "a"
urlParts[2] = "b"
urlParts[3] = "c"
```

```
function parseURL(url){
   //strip off the http://
  if(url.indexOf("http://") != -1){
   url = url.slice(7);
  }

   //split the url into sections
   var urlParts = url.split("/");

   return urlParts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/) (more specifically the [segment](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/docs.html#accessors-segment) method) that is a very good javascript library for URI parsing.